# How can `dd` be used to right-shift data blocks?

Tags: dd, block-device

Consider a 100MB raw block device as a simple example. That is 204800 blocks of 512 bytes each for a total of 102760448 bytes.

The challenge is to shift the first 98MB (200704 blocks) so there is a gap of 2MB (4096 blocks) in front of it. To do this in-place requires that nothing is written to a sector that has not been read. One way to achieve this is to introduce a buffer:

```
$ dd if=/dev/sdj2 count=200704 | mbuffer -s 512 -b 4096 -P 100 | dd of=/dev/sdj2 seek=4096
```

The expectation is that `mbuffer` will store 4096 blocks before passing anything to the writer, thus ensuring that nothing is written to an area that has not been read and that the writer lags the reader by the size of the buffer. The buffer should allow the reader and writer to operate as fast as possible within those constriants.

However, it doesn't seem to work reliably. I've tried using real devices but it never works on them, whereas experiments with a file worked on my 64-bit box but not on my 32-bit box.

First, some preparation:

```
$ dd if=/dev/sdj2 count=200704 | md5sum
0f0727f6644dac7a6ec60ea98ffc6da9
$ dd if=/dev/sdj2 count=200704 of=testfile
```

This doesn't work:

```
$ dd if=/dev/sdj2 count=200704 | mbuffer -s 512 -b 4096 -P 100 -H | dd of=/dev/sdj2 seek=4096
summary: 98.0 MiByte in  4.4sec - average of 22.0 MiB/s
md5 hash: 3cbf1ca59a250d19573285458e320ade
```

This works on 64-bit system but not on 32-bit system:

```
$ dd if=testfile count=200704 | mbuffer -s 512 -b 4096 -P 100 -H | dd of=testfile seek=4096 conv=notrunc
summary: 98.0 MiByte in  0.9sec - average of  111 MiB/s
md5 hash: 0f0727f6644dac7a6ec60ea98ffc6da9
```

**How can this be done reliably?**

---

**notes**

I have read other questions about buffering and looked at `pv`, `buffer` and `mbuffer`. I could only get the latter to work with the required buffer size.

Using intermetiate storage is an obvious solution to the problem that always works but it isn't practical when sufficient spare capacity isn't available.

Test platforms running Arch Linux with `mbuffer` version 20140302.

Comment: I don't suppose it would solve the problem, but out of curiosity why use `mbuffer` at all? Why not instead make `dd` read the entire contents of the block device in one go using `dd bs=102760448`? Of course, one way or the other it's buffered in RAM.

Comment: @Celada - the 100MB example was just an example. Reading 1TB, for example, in one go wouldn't be such a good idea.

Comment: Ah, I understand now, thanks. The `mbuffer` should actually force the second `dd` to lag behind for first and you only need enough RAM to buffer the size of the shift. Too bad `dd` doesn't support reading and writing blocks in backwards order since that would eliminate the problem!

Comment: You didn't list *how* you computed the second md5sum

Comment: @psusi, the second md5 is output by mbuffer (its `-H` argument enables this feature).

Comment: Another tool you haven't listed is [cstream](http://www.cons.org/cracauer/cstream.html). Who knows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a buffer, you could go backwards, one block at a time.

```
for i in $(seq 100 -1 0)
do
    dd if=/dev/thing of=/dev/thing \
       bs=1M skip=$i seek=$(($i+2)) count=1
done
```

Please note that this example is dangerous due to lack of error checking.

It's also slow due to the amount of `dd` calls. If you have memory to spare, you could use a larger blocksize.

With a buffer, **beware pitfalls**. It is *not* sufficient to guarantee a 100% prefill. What you need is a minimum fill throughout the entire process. The buffer must never ever drop below `2M` because otherwise you will have overwritten your yet-to-be-read data again.

So while in theory you could do without any kind of buffer and just chain `dd`:

```
dd if=/dev/thing bs=1M | \
dd bs=1M iflag=fullblock | \
dd bs=1M iflag=fullblock | \
dd of=/dev/thing bs=1M seek=2
```

In practice this does *not* work reliably because there is no guarantee the first `dd` manages to keep reading data, while the last `dd` (with `2M` of "buffer" in between) is already writing.

You can increase your chances considerably by making the in between buffer considerably larger, but even so, it's not reliable.

Unfortunately I do not know a good buffer program with minimum fill property. You need one that stops output as long as there is less than your safety margin within the buffer.

Comment: I accepted this because it answers the original question by demonstrating how `dd` could be used. I think, however, that the real solution is not to use `dd` but instead opt for something that is designed to run backwards like `ddrescue`. I've described a way to do that in an answer.

Comment: @starfry: sure, a program that just does it will be a nice solution. However I'm not at all sure about `ddrescue` here. Not if it expects to be working on different devices, and you have to trick it into accepting your arguments. It might not not have the "minimum buffer fill" property internally either (since with different devices it's not needed), so again it could corrupt your data. You'd have to check in the sourcecode whether it's actually designed for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading 4096 blocks, and then writing those 4096 blocks to the next 4096 blocks of the disk, thus overwriting the second 4096 blocks before they can be read.  You need to read 8129 blocks to get those second 4096 before starting any writing, and then you need to only write 4096 blocks before reading the next 4096.

You didn't mention what kind of filesystem this is.  If it is ext[234], and you have a recent version of e2fsprogs, then you can use `e2image -ra -O 512 /dev/sdj2`.  This also has the added benefit of being smart enough to skip the free space in the volume.

Comment: That makes sense when reading it and I'm going to take another look based upon that. But it doesn't explain why it worked on the test file.

Comment: Re the filesystem, are you referring to the filesystem containing my test file? That's `ext4` but for the block device copy, any filesystem should be irrelevant.

Comment: @starfry, the only way I know of to do this in a generic way is to use the algorithm Emmanuel suggested ( work backwards from the end ), which is what gparted does.

Comment: re the block size, I had tried larger blocks (I should have written that in the question). I found that it didn't become more reliable even a 64K sector buffer. The reliable solution is to run backwards, something that `dd` doesn't do.

Answer (score 1):

A reliable solution requires that you ensure that nothing writes to an area that might not have been read and the only real way to achieve that is to perform the copy in a reverse direction.

The `ddrescue` tool can work in a reverse direction but it refuses to run with the input and output being the same. However it's possible to trick it by duplicating the device node.

I have performed some quick experiments and it appears to work. The command-line is:

```
$ ddrescue -f -R -s 200704s -o 4096s /dev/sdj11 /dev/sdj11_copy
```

The arguments are

- `-f` is required to force it to write to an existing output device
- `-R` tells it to work in a reverse direction
- `-s` tells it how much of the input to copy (I used the `s` suffix to specify the number of sectors)
- `-o` tells it to seek forwards in the output device before writing (specified in sectors again with the `s` suffix)
- `/dev/sdj11` is the block device to read
- `/dev/sdj11_copy` is the block device to write

I created `/dev/sdj11_copy` with `mknod` to match the parameters of `/dev/sdj11`.

I've only done some very quick tests but this does appear to work ok to copy a raw device. It does not work on a file (I could not trick it into going beyond the files being the same)

This doesn't answer my original question which asked how to achieve this with `dd` but I think, having read the other answers, the answer to that is that `dd` cannot do it.

Comment: What happens if `ddrescue` discovers a bad block in this scenario? If it jumps to another area of the disk (to avoid bad blocks), and continues copying from there, it would again overwrite not yet copied parts of your data. If it doesn't expect to work with the same device, it has no reason to take any special measures to prevent various possible data corruption cases.

Comment: I agree that this is a potential issue but I haven't looked at the edge cases, since I was able to use it to do what I needed. There are `ddrescue` options to limit its attempts to recover bad data but I haven't looked into using them.

Comment: The fact that it refuses to operate if the input and output are the same is *probably* a good indication that it isn't safe.